# How to add button on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a pre-populated `UITableViewCell` on which cell have a Label and `UITextField`. Suppose I have a cell with label "map" and I want to add button on that cell how can I do this?
I tried but this is not working.
Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"rateSheetCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100]).text = @"Title";
        ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).placeholder = @"Title";
        ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).text = arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"resource_title"];
        ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    }
    else
    {
        if([arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"label"] isEqualToString:@"OT ($)"]){

            NSInteger desiredLabel = (NSInteger)(arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"label"]);

            //NSString *desiredLabel = arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"label"];
            NSLog(@"Label is>>>>--------%ld", (long)desiredLabel);

            if (indexPath.row == desiredLabel ) {
                UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [b setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
            }


        }
        ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100]).text = arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"label"];
        ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).placeholder = ((UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:100]).text;
        ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).text = arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section][indexPath.row][@"attribute_value"];

        if (indexPath.row == [arrayResourceColumns[indexPath.section] count] - 1)
        {
            ((UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:101]).enabled = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you use tag 100 and 101 to access the cell's subviews. But where did you add them to the cell? They should be added in the `cell == nil` case btw.

Comment: @Khanh the tags are of textlabel and textfield and textlabel and textfield is added in uitableviewcell prototype in storyboard

Comment: @user1699419 Better you can use your own custom table view cell. Inside this u can add sub views like UIButton, UILabel and UITextField etc... Hv you got the solution ?

Comment: @AnandGautam no i does not get u :((

Comment: @user1699419 hv u worked on custom table view cell before ? see these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014105/where-is-a-good-tutorial-for-making-a-custom-uitableviewcell                                                     http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: @AnandGautam no i am not usning custom table view, its a simple table view having table view cell and on which i have a text label n textfield

Answer (score 2):

There is a few ways to add button on `UITAbleViewCell`:
1) If you are using Storyboards you can create cell prototype with button and than you can access this button with `tag` property
2) Subclass `UITableViewCell` and add button on `init`
3) Add button to cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

**UPD**
[Here is](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/) a tutorial how to customize `UITableViewCell` with Storyboards

Comment: @HermannKlecker `UITableViewCell` is a `UIView`, *not* a `UIViewController`, there's no `viewDidLoad` and `init` is the right place to add its subviews.

Comment: Option 3 is possible but not advisable to beginners, although it seems to be so easy - it is not. Unless of course the button is on all cells. Then cellForRow... is a nice place for that. But if the button is not on all cells then it requires some smart coding along with the re-usage logic to avoid strange effects like adding a button every time to the cell when the cell becomes visible or the button appearing in re-used cells when scrolling etc.